# epsilon-NFA to DFA conversion - What will be the final states and do we need to create empty state in DFA?

Tags: finite-automata, nondeterminism

Source of this question and problem:

https://www.javatpoint.com/automata-conversion-from-nfa-with-null-to-dfa

This is the question:

[image]

[image]

So in this figure there are my 1 confusion-:

1. Don't we need a empty set like this-:

[image]

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dmvJp5EgOek&list=PLENQMW_c1dimRCKF3bjUqHaH8dvJkapSw&index=48

Since this is DFA we need to show all transitions, isn't it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When you convert epsilon NFA to NFA, how do you decide the final states of resultant NFA?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/145691/when-you-convert-epsilon-nfa-to-nfa-how-do-you-decide-the-final-states-of-resul)

Comment: No it doesn't unfortunately. :(

Comment: It is a convention that all unspecified transitions in a DFA go to an undrawn non-final state.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct! As you say, in a DFA you need to show all transitions. So, you have to include the empty set state (sometimes called a "sink" state or "dead" state).

Actually this is just the short answer -- the long answer is that *some* authors have defined DFAs so that they don't need to include all transitions, but that definition is not common anymore in modern textbooks. So, the source of the first DFA you showed is probably using that (older) definition.